# Should I create Azure storage & Metastore in the same region?

Tags: azure, storage, metastore

I am going to create a Metasore following the documentation.

Regarding the storage account, I don't understand if it should be in the same region as Metastore.

From documentation:

You can create no more than one metastore per region. Using the same region for your metastore and storage container would be best.
Is it a recommendation or a must?

Another part of the documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It should be in the same region.

Please read through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182371/should-i-create-azure-storage-metastore-in-the-sam) carefully.

Keep in mind, in general, try to keep all related resources in the same region to avoid many obstacles you might face, like latency, and outbound data cost.

Hope that help!